# zenity only displays odd lines when used with cat

Tags: zenity

I'm have problems using zenity.
Here's the script:

```
CHECKED=`cat /tmp/1 | \
         zenity --width=500 --height=450  --list --radiolist --separator=' ' \
                --title="Select Results." \
                --text="show lines" --column="" --column="Files"`
```

The file /tmp/1:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

When I run this script it only displays lines 1,3,5,7,9

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

**1 line in the input file equals 1 column in the dialogue.** Because you are adding radio buttons, **your dialogue has 2 columns** (hence your two `--column` arguments) so your input doesn't match what is to be displayed. In other words, Zenity expects something like this:

```
FALSE
1
FALSE
2
FALSE
3
TRUE
4
```

...where `TRUE/FALSE` signifies whether the radio button is pre-selected when the dialogue opens.

To fix your script without modification of the input file, you can simply prefix each line with an extra line:

```
CHECKED=`cat /tmp/1 | \
         sed 's/^/FALSE\n/g' | \
         zenity --width=500 --height=450  --list --radiolist --separator=' ' \
                --title="Select Results." \
                --text="show lines" --column="" --column="Files"`
```